# Rotate odd numbered pictures

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I write a little script to rotate all the odd numbered pictures of a directory but i can't get it to work. Here is the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

for picture in `ls -v *.png`
do
    if ["$picture" == "picture_$count.png"]
    then
        mogrify -rotate 90 "$picture"
        count=$(($count+2))
    fi
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: include, as the second line of the script, the line *set -x*, which will help you debug your code.

Comment: or execute it as such (`/bin/bash -x ./myscript.sh`)

Answer (score 5):

[Don't parse `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Instead, just let the shell grab all the odd-numbered files for you. It's both safer and simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash

for picture in *[13579].png
do
    mogrify -rotate 90 "$picture"
done
```

`[]` in a shell glob matches any single one of the characters inside, so by listing all the odd digits, the complete pattern matches any file in the current directory that ends in *odd_digit*.png. No need to maintain a running count, and, since filename expansion (i.e. shell globbing) is the last thing that happens to a command line before it's executed, it won't be tripped up by filenames with funky characters.

---

As for what the specific problem with your original script is, it's as [nullterminatedstring](https://superuser.com/a/1249721/302463) pointed out, you need spaces around the `[` and `]` in the `if` line. That's because `[` is not some special syntax for `if`, it's just another command: `/bin/[`, which is a synonym for the [`test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command. (Your shell probably provides it's own built-in version of `[`, for performance reasons, but it should still behave the same as the external command, including all the parsing limitations.)

Without the space between `[` and `"$picture"`, you're telling `bash` to run a command called something like `[picture_1.png` with two arguments: `==` and `picture_1.png]`. Since you *probably* don't have a command called `[picture_1.png` on your computer, your script fails.

With spaces around `[` and `]`, you'd be running the command `[` with four arguments: `picture_1.png`, `==`, `picture_1.png`, and `]`.

Comment: This answer deserves two upvotes: one for “Don't parse `ls`” and one for ``*[13579].png``.

Comment: And another upvote for actually explaining shell globbing and that [ is a synonym for test. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your script isn't working because in line 7 you need a space after `[` and one before `]`.
For example:

```
if [ "$picture" == "picture_$count.png" ]
```

Furthermore your current script only works as long as no odd numbers were left out.

Answer (score 0):

```
max=$(ls *.png | sort -n | tail  -1 | xargs basename -s .png)
for f in seq 1 2 $max
do
    mogrify -rotate 90 $f.png
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the mistakes in the script:

- First the space after `[` and before `]`, commented [here](https://superuser.com/a/1249736/770506) and [here.](https://superuser.com/a/1249721/770506)
- Second, thanks to the comments to [my question](https://superuser.com/q/1249667/770506) of MariusMatutiae and Moses, i change the line seven from `if ["$picture" == "picture_$count.png"]` to `if [ $picture == pagina_$count.png ]` deleting `"`.

Here is the final script.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

for picture in `ls -v *.png`
do
    if [ $picture == picture_$count.png ]
    then
        mogrify -rotate 90 "$picture"
        count=$(($count+2))
    fi
done
```